# Access non public members of a dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown where users can select multiple values with name tag in asp.net. When i use selectevalue i only get first value selected. When i quick watch i can see listitems collection under Items and see selected attribute for each item. This shows correctly based on selected on UI, but i cant access this property as its a non public member. If i can access i can just loop over this collection and get selected values. Any ideas on how i can access this, will there be any issues if i access it. I tried reflection but cant access this list not sure what iam doing wrong. Attaching screen shot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inf9Y.jpg

Comment: Will there be any issues if you access it? Sure, if MS deploys a change to that _implementation detail_. You shouldn't code against private members--they are private for a reason.

Comment: Add you code with reflection.